# C bash на python

Tags: python, bash, mysql

Hi %user%!
Я только начинаю учить python и хочу переписать свой bash скрипт на python.
Не могли бы вы мне помочь, а то я даже не знаю с какой стороны подойти к вопросу.

Код моего скрипта:

```
#/bin/bash
. "/etc/CFG_FULL.cfg"
 
#nmap --excludefile $pwd/db_ip_exclude.txt -sn 192.168.212.0/22 | egrep -v "Host|nmap" | awk '{print $5}' > $pwd/db_ip_test.txt
 
cd $pwd/port_up_down
#ip=192.168.213.50
while read ip
do
cat /dev/null > $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log
#/home/user/test/port_up_down/port_status.sh $ip
cat /var/log/remote/switches.log | grep -w $ip | grep Port | awk '{ print $7 }' | sort -n | uniq >> $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log
cat /var/log/remote/switches.log.1 | grep -w $ip | grep Port | awk '{ print $7 }' | sort -n | uniq >> $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log
zcat /var/log/remote/switches.log.2.gz | grep " $ip " | grep Port | awk '{ print $7 }' | sort -n | uniq >> $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log
cat $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log | sort -n | uniq > $pwd/port_up_down/log/$ip.log
done < $pwd/db_ip_test.txt
```

Пока я могу только открыть файл :(

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
f1 = open("/var/log/remote/switches.log")
xString = f1.readlines()
nambers = len(xString)
xString = [xString.replace("\n","") for xString in xString]
for cntr in range(0,nambers):
    print (xString[cntr])
f1.close()
```

*Буду благодарен за любую помощь!!!*

UPD 0.1
Данные из файлов которые я парсю есть mysql, у меня данные syslog дублируются в базу, может будет проще брать данные от туда?
Но мне надо чтоб брались данные только за 3 месяца.
Так как в bash не очень удобно работать с базой я не рассматривал такой вариант.
UPD 0.2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb
import string

select_sql = "SELECT `datetime`, `host`, `msg` FROM `logs` WHERE host = '{0}' and msg                           LIKE '{1}';"

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="121788",db="syslog")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(select_sql.format('192.168.212.60','Port 22 link%'))
for k in cursor.fetchall():
    print (k[2])
```

[вывод](http://pastebin.com/naMsHwKj)

как мне теперь вывести только в столбец в этой строке
пробовал:

```
aa = k.split()
print (aa[2])
```

выводит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run_port.py", line 12, in <module>
    aa = k.split()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Вот так вот заработало:

```
for k in cursor.fetchall():
bb = str(k[2])
aa = bb.split()
print (aa[1])
```

UPD 0.3
Не получается реализовать сортировку и удаление дублей из масива.
Мне нужно по аналогии с **sort -n | uniq**

Comment: я бы  и башевый вариант переписал, у вас там безумное дублирование.

Comment: Буду рад любой адекватной критике.  
Покажите свой вариант и если можно объясните почему ваш лучше.  
Интересно в чем я ошибся.

Comment: вот так:    

    #/bin/bash
    . "/etc/CFG_FULL.cfg"
    while read ip;do

     (cat /var/log/remote/switches.log /var/log/remote/switches.log.1;
      zcat /var/log/remote/switches.log.2.gz) | grep -w $ip | grep Port | awk '{ print $7 }' | sort -nu > $pwd/port_up_down/log/$ip.log

    done < $pwd/db_ip_test.txt

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!  
Так и правда на много лучше!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"""выборка из mysql"""

import MySQLdb
select_sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip={0} and port={1};"

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="r",passwd="r",db="r")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(select_sql.format('192.168.0.1','24'))
for k in cursor.fetchall():
    print k
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Попробую так.